# Child element go out of parent

Tags: html, css

Lets say we have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <textarea id="input"></textarea>
        <textarea id="output"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this css:

```
html,body,#main{
    height:100%;
}

html{ border: 1px solid red; }
body{ border: 1px solid green; }
#main{ border: 1px solid blue; }
#navbar{ height: 30px; }

textarea{
    width: 45%;
    height: 60%;
    resize: vertical;
}

#input{
    float: left;
}

#main{
    float: right;
}
```

If you look at result then you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fzze/) body is out of html tag, #main is out of body and html tag.. How I can make so all the elements to not go out of parent height? So I want the result to be like this:

[image]

Comment: You can add margin-left and margin-right on #main and overflow: hidden on body! Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fzze/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the `body` has defaults margins of `8px;`

Start by resetting those.

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Additionally, `borders` are not calculated into the heights, rather they are added. Therefore the heights were really 100% + 2px borders. You can change this by adding `box-sizing: border-box;`.

This will solve the problems with the `html`/`body`. Now, for `#main` - the reason this was occuring, was because a `30px` `nav` was placed outside of it. `#main` was actually 100%, however it was `100%` under `30px`, that's why you saw a gap.

[**Updated jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fBUj/)